# how can I split a frame between two frames?

Tags: java, jframe, jpanel, layout-manager, grid-layout

I am using grid layout in a frame and I want to put two panels in this frame in which one of them takes one third of the frame size and the other two third of the screen, how can I do that?

I have tried this but it didnot work for me:

code:

```
this.setLayout(new GridLayout(2, 1));
Dimension d2 = new Dimension(2*this.getHeight()/3, this.getWidth());
Dimension d3 = new Dimension(this.getHeight() / 3, this.getWidth()); 

panel1.setPreferredSize(d2);
panel1.setMaximumSize(d2);
panel1.setMinimumSize(d2);

panel2.setPreferredSize(d3);
panel2.setMaximumSize(d3);
panel2.setMinimumSize(d3);

this.add(panel1);
this.add(panel2);
```

thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

GridLayout is not the right layout manager to use in this situation. GridLayout sets the width and height of all components in the container equal to each other. Attempting to set the preferred sizes of the components manually will have no effect since the layout manager takes care of that internally.

You can instead use GridBagLayout, and control the weight of the components using GridBagConstraints:

```
GridBagLayout layout = new GridBagLayout();
GridBagConstraints constraints = new GridBagConstraints();
constraints.fill = GridBagConstraints.BOTH;
this.setLayout(layout);

JPanel panel1 = new JPanel(), panel2 = new JPanel();

constraints.gridwidth = GridBagConstraints.REMAINDER;
constraints.weightx = 1;
constraints.weighty = 1.0/3.0;
layout.setConstraints(panel1, constraints);
this.add(panel1);

constraints.weighty = 2.0/3.0;
layout.setConstraints(panel2, constraints);
this.add(panel2);
```

Comment: the width of each panel is not as the width of the base frame , how can I do that without changing the width of each panel?

Comment: Just to clarify: you do not want the width of the panels to change when the size of the frame does?

Comment: the frame size is constant, and I want each panel to have the width of the frame but the difference between them is the length of each one.

Comment: What do you mean by "the difference between them is the length of each one"? Do you just want the ratio of the heights of the panels to be 2:1 (i.e. 120 and 60)? If not, can you explain further?

Comment: In that case I edited my answer slightly; see if that meets your needs.

Comment: each panel is now in the center of the frame , I need each panel width to be as the width of the the frame containing them, moreover the ratio after changing the code is still 1:1 .

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/93701/discussion-between-flashdisk-and-tnt).

Comment: Try this latest edit. I set the x-weight of the constraints to 1, so the panels should occupy the entire width of the frame. Also, if you look closely, the ratio is in fact 1:2 (that was the case even before the edit).